# Is there some type of hard link which breaks when the content of the file changes

Tags: linux, filesystems

I want to save space by hard linking duplicate files but also minimize the risk of breaking the programs/projects at the same time.

As long as the file is read, the hard link should persist but even modifying the content of the file should break the link.

Comment: Use snapshot to create two files on write. hard links point to the same inode.

Comment: Could you please expand on it a bit? I don't quite understant what you mean by using snapshots. @stark